# Low-cost servo with digital control interfaces?

Tags: otherservos, i2c

Some years ago, there where some projects that provided hardware and software to perform modifications on standard hobby servos to convert them to digital servos, with all the advantages that come with it.

- [OpenServo](http://openservo.com/) is a little outdated, and does not seem to be worked on anymore, and there is no hardware to buy.
- Sparkfun has its [own version](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9014) of the OpenServo, which at least is available for buying.

Do you know if there are other mods, or even complete low cost digital servos? I am mostly interested in position feedback, and servo chaining.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it really seems like Openservo is even more irrelevant now. You can get cheap Dynamixel-clones for around \$20, whereas with Openservo you have to buy A \$15 board, a \$15 hobby servo and then disassemble then desolder then resolder then reassemble them yourself. Just get a real "digital robot" servo and save yourself the hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the v3 OpenServo is out of stock.

In fact we are working on a new version 4 of OpenServo that will modernise the codebase.

There are no timelines for the v4 as yet, but work has only just started.

I would recommend the SparkFun board for now.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of additional research I have found one other project very similar to the OpenServo project. They are called supermodified servos. Some of the web sources are not available anymore, but there is the source for the project, which is quite advanced on google code and on github:

- [zosupermodified](http://code.google.com/p/zosupermodified/) - source code for the controller
- [Supermodified-Servo](https://github.com/jandetlefsen/Supermodified-Servo) - eagle files